# Is it possible to open an .ai file in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I currently dont have Illustrator but I do have Photoshop, is it possible to open a .ai vector file and save as JPG/PNG in a desired size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, .AI files will be rasterized when you **open** them into Photoshop. You'll be provided with a dialog asking you for the dimensions you'd like to render the file pixels at:

[image: Import PDF dialog]

You could alternatively place an .AI file in an existing Photoshop Document using **File** ▸ ***Place...*** Using the place method, the .ai file is retained as a vector smart object within Photoshop.

You can also see a list of the types of files that Photoshop can open by opening up the "Files of type" dropdown box

[image: PS open file dialog]

Comment: This just opens as a blank image for me :(